# Remove specific rules from tailwind base

Tags: tailwind-css

I want to remove the img rule from tailwind base, is there anyway to do that?

Tailwind base adds this:

```
img, video {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

I want to remove that rule. Overrideing it with `initial` will not get my expected result.

So unfortunately i cannot do:

```
img, video {
    max-width: initial;
    height: initial;
}
```

`height: initial` doesnt seems to be the same as having no height attribute at all. If i override height to initial the height will be the source of the image and height attributes on the `<img height="200">` will not be respected.

Comment: Have you tried overriding with `height: min-content`?

Comment: Yep, i have tried to override with all height attributes, even `unset`

Comment: Have you tried `height: revert-layer;`?

Comment: Hadnt tried that, seems to be invalid property value, however i tried with revert

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it's

As the [documentation](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/adding-custom-styles#adding-base-styles) says, you can override the base properties by using `@layer base`.

It's available from `v1.9.0`.

```css
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;

@layer base {
  img, video {
    max-width: initial;
    height: initial;
  }
}
```